# Change 5GHz control channel of my Asus RT-AC86U with SSH?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssh

So I am having a problem with Smart Connect. When I enable smart connect, control channels are set to auto and this causes my router to set my 5GHz control channel to 157. This causes a problem because those control channels are illegal in Europe and this cause my 5GHz to not be visible/usable. Is there a way I can change the 5GHz control channel to 36 from SSH so that I can use the Smart Connect feature?